# Does events batch count as single or multiple events in Azure's Event Hubs/IoT Hub

Tags: azure

Azure Event Hubs and IoT Hub services allows sending messages in batch to optimize sending. Say I am batching 10 messages, will it count as 10 messages or 1 message for billing?